# How do I put images on the iPad Simulator

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator, ipad

Is there anyway of placing images on the iPad simulator?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can save images from Safari.

I don't think there is a different (easier) way.

Comment: Maybe you could type in a "file://localhost/..." URL into Safari on the simulator to load a photo from somewhere on your Mac?

Comment: Not localhost, but I suppose file://Users/username/... should work

Comment: Just drag-and-drop from Mac to Simulator screen will work. No need of URL writing. Click-and-hold the opened image in safari and save to camera roll.

Answer (score 3):

if you drag and drop from the OS onto the simulator, it will load the image into safari, where you can then save to your camera roll

Answer (score 2):

I've done this by writing a little throwaway app that contains the images I want, then use the UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum API call to save them from my bundle.